# displaying xaml page in content place holder of aspx page

Tags: c#, xaml

i am now trying to display my arcgis map from c# silverlight application project (xaml) into this content place holder of aspx page. i just want it to be displayed into the content place holder. any ideas how to do this? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is embedded as object tag in HTML, so you just need to create proper  tag which refer to your silverlight app inside the content placeholder.